# Is there a way to add offset to Rockshox Reverb AXS dropper seatpost?

Tags: saddle, seatpost

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to add offset to a Rockshox Reverb AXS seatpost? I saw a company called FAIR Bicycle that developed hardware to add offset (+ or -) to a Reverb, but it's not compatible with the AXS version.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to get the saddle positioned far back, where you want it. An alternative solution to having a setback post is to have a saddle with rails that allow for largest fore-aft adjustment.

There are not many of them, and most of them are styled for "touring" applications, but such saddles exist.

[image: Velo Orange]

Note that this Velo Orange saddle is also quite high, meaning you'd need to insert your dropper seatpost deeper into the frame to preserve the same fully extended height.

Finally, there is a possibility to get the hardware CNC'd or 3D-printed for your specific post. Have you tried to contact FAIR bicycle? Who knows, maybe something is already in works for AXS seatposts?

Comment: That looks like a knockoff of the old Brooks saddles which really weren't for touring. And they really don't make saddles on rails for fore/aft adjustment anymore? _haven't been on a bike in ages_

Comment: @FreeMan With modern saddles, you usually get about ±20 mm of adjustment using just the rails. A setback seatpost could give another 25mm of rear offset. I'd say that it is impossible to get what one needs with a non-offset seatpost by just relying on the normal saddle adjustment range. Modern MTB frames have quite steep seat tube angles, and most of dropper seatposts have 0 mm of setback. That combination works for many but not for all body types and proportions.